# Casting string to integer in mvel

Tags: java, casting, mvel

How to cast string to integer in MVEL

`Props['MyInteger'] = java.lang.Integer.ParseInt('//xpath to some string')`

Other java typing works in my code.  for example

`Props['MyArrayList'] = new java.util.ArrayList()`

Comment: What is the question?What is the problem?

Comment: the problem is that
`Props['MyInteger'] = java.lang.Integer.ParseInt('//xpath to some string')`
throws an error.  
what is the proper way to cast in mvel

Comment: Solved:
`Props['MyInteger'] = (int)('//xpath to some string')`

Answer (score 1):

Solved: 
'Props['MyInteger'] = (int)('//xpath to some string')'

Comment: looking here: https://github.com/imona/tutorial/wiki/MVEL-Guide in the Assignements sections, seems like you don't even need the cast at all. Does this work? `'Props['MyInteger'] = '//xpath to some string'`